# CAS working in localhost

Tags: cas

I have a problem whit cas for a couple of weeks. I am trying to run **georchestra** whit cas but when I login I have this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
  PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
    Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

I have seen a lot of post and I've tried a lot of solutions but none of these works, so I want some help too dissable SSL secure.

The complete log file is these

```
2013-05-20 18:38:39 CommonUtils [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1852)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:982)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1278)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:281)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:33)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:130)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.camptocamp.security.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:14)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:350)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:208)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:279)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the CAS server's certificate self-signed?  If so, then your JVM for the client most likely does not trust the certificate.

This link has a bunch of information on dealing with potential SSL issues:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/SSL+Troubleshooting+and+Reference+Guide

Comment: yes, the certificate is self-signed i will see the link and i will let you know the results, thanks for the help

Comment: Well i use the comand keytool -import ".crt location" -keystore "cacerts location" and i try with these  keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file tmp/incommon-root-cert.der -alias incommon but i still have the same error when i login

Comment: Your CAS server was signed with an InCommon certificate?  And the command you ran is to import that certificate for the client?

Comment: No, it was signed with the certificate that i generated in my case was georchestra,crt and alias localhost, and i try with the command keytool -import -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-opnejdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /etc/ssl/certs/georchestra.crt -alias localhost, but all that i am making it will work only in one computer, it will be for a Live DVD based on debian Wheezy whit a installation of GeOrchestra and CAS client authenticator

Comment: I'm not sure I followed the steps that you took.  I recommend following the steps defined in the SSL Troubleshooting and Reference guide completely to set up the certificate for both the server and client.  Those have been tested pretty extensively.

Comment: Scott i use the guide you gave me an when i set the debug mode these is the error that i have

%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
TP-Processor10, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
TP-Processor10, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-8443-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-8443-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
http-8443-1, called closeSocket()
http-8443-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:

Comment: fatal, certificate_unknown
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
http-8443-1, called closeSocket()
http-8443-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-8443-1, called close()
http-8443-1, called closeInternal(true)
TP-Processor10, called closeSocket()
TP-Processor10, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation

Comment: failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
TP-Processor10, called close()
TP-Processor10, called closeInternal(true)

Comment: thanks for the help Scott i'm near to finish mi work whit the help you gave me

Comment: Solved recreating the keys and then creating the keystore fron the key generated and the added to the cacerts